# Pygame sprite not moving when key pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am working on a christmas pygame game and I'm trying to have a bag move and keep moving when I press the left or right arrow keys. There is no error but when I press the keys nothing happens. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Heres the code thanks!:

```
import pygame
import sys

width = 1024
height = 768

left = (-1, 0)
right = (1, 0)

sprite1 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/santabag2.png")

icon1 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/santa-claus.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon1)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Gift Catcher")
background_image = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/wintervillage.png")
running = True
while running:
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sprite1, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rect = sprite1.get_rect()
                rect = rect.move((1, 0))
                screen.blit(sprite1, rect)
            elif pygame.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                rect = sprite1.get_rect()
                rect = rect.move((-1, 0))
                screen.blit(sprite1, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes. The first mistake is a typo. It has to be `event.key` rather than `pygame.key`.

Also, you must `blit` the sprite in the application loop, not the event loop, in the location stored in `rect`. Get the rectangle (`rect`) before the loop. Move the rectangle in the event loop and `blit` the sprite in every frame at `rect`:

```py
rect = sprite1.get_rect()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rect = rect.move(1, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                rect = rect.move(-1, 0)
              
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0)) 
    screen.blit(sprite1, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

Note, you can use [`move_ip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) rather than [`move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move):

<s>`rect = rect.move((-1, 0))`</s>

```py
rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
```

---

However, use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` for a continuous movement:

```py
rect = sprite1.get_rect()
speed = 1

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * speed
    rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * speed
              
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0)) 
    screen.blit(sprite1, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame

icon1 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/santa-claus.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon1)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Gift Catcher")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background_image = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/wintervillage.png")

sprite1 = pygame.image.load("Firstpygamegame/santabag2.png")
rect = sprite1.get_rect()
speed = 1

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * speed
    rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * speed
              
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0)) 
    screen.blit(sprite1, rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```